# What do I do if the Encounter Finder is missing from my inventory after the Miracle Johnson mission?

Tags: yakuza-0

In *Yakuza 0* (PC), I did the Miracle Johnson mission and chose the black package. I got the Encounter Finder just to go save, check my inventory, and find out it is not in there. What do I do?

Comment: @pppery I noticed that you edited out the platform information (PC) from the title, which I think was a good idea to make it more concise. However, I also think it would be helpful to keep that information in the body of the question since it might be relevant for some answers. Please add the platform information back to the question body next time you edit a title like this. That way, we can make sure we don’t lose any relevant details for the question.